# Read-Only Postgraphile-CLI API

Tags: postgresql, postgraphile

I am currently implementing a public API for a Open Data Platform with Postgraphile creating the needed API for me. The API should be completly public, with no authentification whatsoever and because of that the API should only implement read-only queries. Has anyone found a possibility to use Postgraphile-CLI to only create read-only functionality?

So far I have sucessfully setup a Postgraphile-CLI API for my postgres databases, with a user that only has the "GRANT SELECT" for the schemas in Postgres. However, this doesn't seem to work for my use case, since I still can use the mutation in graphql and insert or delete data from my schemas.
Since I don't know too much about postgres database administration, I therefor wonder If it is possible to just not provide mutations with Postgraphile-CLI.

Kind regards

Grigorios

EDIT0: I have found the mistake with my Postgres database rights. That may solve that read-only problem, but If anybody knows an answer to the initial question, I would be curious to know anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options:

1. Use permissions, as you suggest, along with the `--no-ignore-rbac` option - you will have to ensure your database permissions are and remain correct (no default grants to the `public` role, for example) for this to work
2. Use PostGraphile's `--disable-default-mutations` (`-M`) option; this will stop the CRUD mutations being generated but won't prevent custom mutation functions from being exposed, if you have any
3. Skip the `MutationPlugin` via `--skip-plugins graphile-build:MutationPlugin` - this will prevent the `Mutation` type from being added to the schema in the first place, so no mutations can be added.

For a real belt-and-braces approach, why not all three?

```
postgraphile \
  --no-ignore-rbac \
  --disable-default-mutations \
  --skip-plugins graphile-build:MutationPlugin
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, Benjie! Your name is one of the names with Postgraphile I read the most. You are very helpful.